# Stop PHP from rounding my numbers

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've created a invoice creator but it keeps rounding my numbers. How do I stop this?

[image]

You see at stukprijs = 206,61 and total is 206 total needs to be 206,61 as well.

My code:

```
public function makepdf(Request $request){
    $data = $request->all();

    $data['totaal1'] = $data['stukprijs1'] * $data['aantal1'];
```

I sent the values from a form field with post.

The app is build in Laravel.

Comment: force a float:  `$data['totaal1'] = floatval($data['stukprijs1'] * $data['aantal1']);`

Comment: Jordy, is there more code that you can share?  What is the code that is actually displaying the Total?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need both elements in the multiplication to be floats if you don't want PHP to force a round on the result.

```
$data['totaal1'] = floatval($data['stukprijs1']) * floatval($data['aantal1']);
```